# Is having a strong background in plain TeX a prerequisite to learn how to work with PSTricks or PostScript internal details?

Tags: pstricks

Question has been elaborated in the title.

Comment: @xport: There are very few exceptions, but usually you really should ask the question in the actual post.

Comment: @Hendrik, could you rewrite your comment in an easier-to-understand sentence?

Comment: @xport: In several recent questions, you've only put something like "The question has been written above" in the body of your post. Also here, the question is only in the title. You should ask the question in the _body_ of the post. (And if possible, the title should be a bit shorter.)

Comment: @Hendrik. OK. I understand now. But, do you have idea how to shorten my title above? I am learning English so I have very limited skill to shorten sentences while maintaining the important idea remains conserved.

Comment: @xport: My main point was that you should repeat the question in the body of your post, and usually you should elaborate a bit. Here, _a bit_ (one sentence) is quite enough. Moreover, I think that your English is quite good. (A possible shorter title is "Do I need a strong background in plain TeX for understanding PSTricks internals?" Then you could mention PostScript in the body of your post. But as I said, that's not my main point here.)

Comment: @Hendrik. OK. Next time I will repeat the question with a bit syntatic sugar. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSTricks itself uses only plain TeX and lets nearly all calculations done by PostScript which is passed into the ps file as raw PostScript code. Informations from PostScript can be send back to TeX when running the ps file one time with Ghostscript.

- *.sty:  that  are only the wrapper files for LaTeX to put informations in the logfile
- *.tex is the TeX compatible file which is read by `\input` from the
  sty-file, when using latex
- *.pro is the PostScript prolog file which is pure PostScript code which
  is used by one of the dvi-pdf or
  dvi-ps converters.

It is also possible to write real LaTeX packages which uses the PostScript interface. That a lot of PSTricks packages are written in TeX has only a historical background. However when you want to understand the internals then you need as usual for all LaTeX packages some knowledge in TeX.

Comment: @Hendrik You said 'write real LaTeX packages which...', you mean by the code provide with PSTricks or just in general? It is interesting how LaTeX is re-discovering itself as a transformation tool, i.e PostScript, JavaScript, XML etc...

Comment: I meant packages for PSTricks like `pst-am`, which has no TeX-Version

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure Herbert will answer this, but I honestly cannot see how it would be. PSTricks has a well-defined interface and that is what matters.

TeX itself doesn't know anything about PostScript. There's a single primitive `\special` that sticks its contents in the dvi file. Some programs that read dvis do something *special* with these, `dvips` for example.